# Streams in computing

Tags: python, sockets, stream, communication

In the world of computing, majorly i've been reading python programming language and the socket module 
I understand that the sockets in communication are just communications end-points, which every communication done uses a socket.

```
import socket
#Importing the low-level socket module in python
```

But what i have been trying to grasp is streams, i understand them though, but is it enough to just think of streams as the road connecting two sockets together where other things like bytes and packets drive on from one place to the other or there is more to it? Thanks for your simple but through explanation

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a "file" and a "stream" is that a stream cannot be rewound and read (or written) again.  Also, a "stream" usually has no concept of "framing", meaning it is just a pipe with bytes flowing through, as opposed to a "message queue" or a "datagram socket".  TCP sockets are considered stream sockets, whereas UDP ones are "datagram" sockets meaning that the boundaries between message bodies are explicit in the protocol.  With a stream you often need to implement your own framing or "envelope" protocol on top.